# Windows 10 - non crisp fonts - how can I fix it?

Tags: windows-10, fonts, cleartype

I've been seeing all articles and questions in the internet but still didn't find a solution.

Problem is this :

[image]

On the right side, you see a blurry font as opposed to the left side where you see explorer.

**EDIT:**

[Some reported that the image is still blurry, this is because SO/imgur reduces quality. here is the file of the image in 100% quality.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F_TqHSjPCjY-C-rXsuHwMfwxQ1Jgs3fp/view?usp=sharing)

Performance options are set :

[image]

ClearType is Off

Fix App that is blurry : on (I've also tested with Off).

[image]

Driver is updated

I can not understand how the same screen , two different windows , different font rendering.

Question :

How can I set the right side to be crisp like on the left side? If it's a different font, then where do I change it ?

Comment: The image on the left (Explorer) seems to have a more blurry font than the right.

Comment: Maybe visit optometrist?

Comment: Ouugh.... SO reduces quality of image....

Comment: Have you gone through the ClearType initial adjustment?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  Yes I did , but then disabled it. Are you sayig that it is a one way settings without a revert ? do you know how to solve it ?

Comment: Your image requires permission to access. Please put it on https://imgur.com/

Comment: @harrymc thanks. fixed : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F_TqHSjPCjY-C-rXsuHwMfwxQ1Jgs3fp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I still see the Explorer font as much more blurry...

Comment: @harrymc make sure you are not in zoom mode. anyway , it is clearly that the right side fonts are different than the left one. in their boldness/sharpness

Comment: Do you do agree this? LEFT----------------------------RIGHT ?

Comment: The “blurry” font on the right is antialiased and smooth. The “not-blurry” font on the left is pixelated and not antialiased. I consider the font displayed on the right (which you call blurry) better quality and easier to read. I get the impression you don’t.

Comment: @StarCat Yes. I'm after aliased fonts. not antialiased fonts.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, no, I'm stating that ClearType is not simply on/off, but that it requires *setup*. See https://winaero.com/change-cleartype-settings-windows-10/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik once you activate once the clear type wizard , you can undo it , even if you disable cleartype